# reCaptcha + RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, recaptcha

How can I import recaptcha using requirejs. I already tryed several things and nothing works.

I need do that to be able to render it by my own using the method render of reCaptcha once it has been loaded.

```js
require.config({
    paths: {
        'recaptcha': 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api'
    }
});

require( ['recaptcha'], function( recaptcha ) {
    // do something with recaptcha
    // recaptcha.render  /// at this point recaptcha is undefined
  console.log(recaptcha);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.2.0/require.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I have a solution for you. So what ends up happening is that recaptcha can't render until it has loaded what it needs from the google api.

So what you need to do is the following (also don't use http/https in your paths):

```
require.config({
  paths: {
      'recaptcha': '//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit'
  }
});
```

Now that will allow a callback to be executed after the necessary libraries have been downloaded from the google API.
This callback needs to be global unfortunately.

JS

```
var requireConfig = {
 paths: {
  'recaptcha': '//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?    onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit'
 }
};

function render(id) {
  console.log('[info] - render');
  recaptchaClientId = grecaptcha.render(id, {
    'sitekey': '6LdntQgUAAAAANdffhZl0tIHw0fqT3MwNOlAI-xY',
    'theme': 'light'
  });
};
window.renderRecaptcha = render;

var onloadCallback = function() {
  console.log('[info] - onLoadCallback');
  if (!document.getElementById('g-recaptcha')) {
    return;
  }
  window.renderRecaptcha('g-recaptcha');
};

requirejs.config(requireConfig);

require(['recaptcha'], function(recaptcha) {

});
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div id="g-recaptcha"></div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.14/require.js">    </script>


</body>
```

I hope that works for you!

Link to Example: https://jsbin.com/kowepo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Please include a working example in the form of a jsfiddle, a jsbin or even a Stack Snippet. When I tried adding `onload=` to the OP's code, it did not work.

Comment: Hey sorry. I should've done that from the start. I've edited with a link to jsbin

Comment: Yeah I understand, it works but don't help me much, because of these limitations breaks my organization :(

Comment: Could you elaborate how it's breaking your organization? What you can do is put all the render logic that adds to the global scope inside a module, then shim it. What you end up with is a module abstracting all that global yuckiness into a reusable module. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Nope your solution works just perfect, later I realize that I am able to expose a global function from inside of my module if I receive a reference for windows... so I had no problem anymore.

Comment: @HerbertPimentel please share in an answer if you'd be so kind!

Comment: I have applied the exactly same code above. inside of my module I only exposed a callback direct to the window object such as window.onloadCallback = function(){ ... }

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old, but I discovered another solution recently in my project that does not require the creation of global methods. This solution ended up being a very simple addition to the OP's first attempt at using Google reCaptcha with RequireJS.

In `main.js`, add the following: (exactly like the OP has it)

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'recaptcha': 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api'
    }
});
```

In your JS file where you're doing the explicit render, do the following:

```
require( ['recaptcha'], function(recaptcha) {
    // render when recaptcha is ready
    // injecting recaptcha here will give access to the grecaptcha object and it's ready method
    grecaptcha.ready(function()
        grecaptcha.render('elementId', {
          'sitekey': 'SITE_KEY',
          'callback': someCallbackMethod
        });
    );
});
```

This worked for me and I believe it's a cleaner solution!